# In RAML, is there a way to provide different examples based on a query parameter

Tags: api, rest, raml

I guess the question is pretty self-explanatory. I have a query parameter called `expand` which, when provided, will provided embedded representations of related resources. Otherwise it provides links to said resources. Is there a way to provide these two examples based on the value of `expand` in RAML?

Answer (score 3):

RAML 1.0 come with this support, see https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/issues/107 for details

Answer (score 1):

An example in RAML 1.0:

```
/{songId}:
    get:
      responses:
        200:
          body:
            application/json:
              type: object
              properties:
                title: string
                description?: string
                artist:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    name: string
                    is_band: boolean
              examples:
                song1:
                  description: Example for a song without description and the artist is not a band.
                  content:
                    title: Yesterday
                    artist:
                      name: The Beatles
                      is_band: true
                song2:
                  description: Example for a song with description and the artist is a band.
                  content:
                    title: How deep is your love
                    description: That could be a description for the song.
                    artist:
                      name: Calvin Harris
                      is_band: false
```